# why wild card not working in if clause bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, glob

Hi below is my code in shell scripting

```
for i in "${status_array[@]}"
do
        if [[ $i == "*start*"  ]]; then
                echo "$i"
                echo "${service_array[$count]}  $i "
        fi

        count=`expr $count + 1`
        isStarted=""
done

for j in "${status_array[@]}"
do
        echo "$j"
done
```

In this script for below loop for j , $j shows few values as stop.waiting and few as start/running. but for above loop control comes to the if clause block. and also here $i shows every value as start/running, so why this happen in that case.

Comment: On a side note, don't use `expr` in bash. `((count++))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change `"*start*"` to `*"start"*`. If you place glob patterns around quotes, it would be matched in literal form.

Comment: As is test value is **a single word**, he doesn't need quotes at all.

Comment: @ÉdouardLopez Yes it's only optional.

Answer (score 3):

When using `[[ ]]` you don't need to quote your strings as

> **Word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed**  on  the words
>   between  the  [[  and  ]]; tilde expansion, parameter and variable
>   expansion, arithmetic expansion, command  substitution, process
>   substitution,   and   quote   removal  are  performed.

And **quoting disable your glob** pattern.

### Solution

So **remove the quotes** in your `[[ ]]` test:

```bash
if [[ $i == *start*  ]]; then
    echo "$i"
fi
```

### Tests

Let's see what `bash` is doing with `set -x`

#### With quotes

```bash
set -x; i=starter; [[ $i == "*start*" ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"; set +x
+ set -x
+ i=starter
+ [[ starter == \*\s\t\a\r\t\* ]]
+ echo no
no
```

See everything, even the `*` are escaped.

#### Without quotes

```bash
set -x; i=starter; [[ $i == *start* ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"; set +x
+ set -x
+ i=starter
+ [[ starter == *start* ]]
+ echo yes
yes
```

### Moar

[What is the difference between test, [ and [[ ?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)